# Detectiing a incoming Facetime call in ios

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there anyway to detect an incoming Facetime call in ios. I tried `CTCallCenter` but it seems like it only works with cellular calls and not facetime calls.. I am using following code to detect facetime call but no success.

```
 self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
 self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* myCall) {
    NSString *call = myCall.callState;
    if ([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected])
        NSLog(@"Call has been disconnected");
    else if([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateDialing])
        NSLog(@"Call start");
    else if ([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateConnected])
        NSLog(@"Call has just been connected");
    else if([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateIncoming])
        NSLog(@"Call is incoming");
    else
        NSLog(@"None");
};
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you want to make FaceTime calls through your phone?

Comment: @Neeku no i want to detect an incoming facetime call. when someone calls me i using facetime i want my application will detect it.. and pause or play my player

Comment: Ok. I get you. I was searching around this, and I think I have the answer for you. Check it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an app-specific detection for every app that needs pausing your playback. You should use [`AVAudioSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to detect any kind of audio interruption and notify your music player to pause.

See this image and explanation from Apple's documentation:

[image]

> `AVAudioSession` gives you control your app’s audio behavior. You can:
>
> - Select the appropriate input and output routes for your app
> - Determine how your app integrates audio from other apps
> - Handle interruptions from other apps
> - Automatically configure audio for the type of app your are creating

So, you can use the `AVAudioSession` API to handle any incoming calls that can be a cellular call or a FaceTime one, or even anything third-party like Viber, Tango, Line, etc.

You can also check the [AddMusic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845) sample app to see how it's implemented.

Comment: I am not using Audiosession or Avplayer. The player was build using ffmpeg so its not possible to use avplayer or audiosession here.

Comment: Oh, hmm... that makes things a bit complicated then, I think. I'll update my answer if I can find a solution to this.